# Is this ExportRenderer still required in Xamarin Forms 4.4 +

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a couple of questions about the WKWebview in Xamarin Forms

1) From https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/3346:

To opt-in to using WkWebView add the following to the AssemlyInfo.cs file of your iOS C# project file

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.WkWebViewRenderer))]
```

Is this assembly still necessary to use in Xamarin Forms 4.4? Apparently WKWebView is the default view in XF4.4 so it's unnecessary?

2) Are there any visual changes between the UIWebView and the WKWebview? I updated my app from XF3.4 to 4.4 because I heard of the WebView change, but there doesn't seem to be any visual difference, but there is one weird bug in 4.4 where the loading icon won't disappear from the middle of my screen even though my page appears to have loaded properly...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the latest [document of webView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#uiwebview-deprecation-and-app-store-rejection-itms-90809), `WKWebView` has replaced `UIWebView` since `Xamarin.forms 4.5`:

> Starting in April 2020, Apple will reject apps that still use the
>   deprecated UIWebView API. **While Xamarin.Forms has switched to
>   WKWebView as the default,** there is still a reference to the older SDK
>   in the Xamarin.Forms binaries. Current iOS linker behavior does not
>   remove this, and as a result the deprecated UIWebView API will still
>   appear to be referenced from your app when you submit to the App
>   Store.
>
> A preview version of the linker is available to fix this issue. To
>   enable the preview, you will need to supply an additional argument
>   --optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type to the linker.

The prerequisites for this to work are:

- **Xamarin.Forms 4.5 or higher** – Pre-release versions of Xamarin.Forms
  4.5 can be used.
- **Xamarin.iOS 13.10.0.17 or higher** – Check your Xamarin.iOS version in
  Visual Studio. This version of Xamarin.iOS is included with Visual
  Studio for Mac 8.4.1 and Visual Studio 16.4.3.
- **Remove references to UIWebView** – Your code should not have any
  references to UIWebView or any classes that make use of UIWebView.

Have a look at [this thread](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7323#issuecomment-574866448) would help.

For your first question, I think it is no longer needed in Xamarin.forms 4.5+.

For your second question, if you have any question, you can open an issue in Github of Xamarin.forms.

Comment: Hm, well it's not possible for me to upgrade to XF 4.5 because we are in the middle of a sprint right now, what should I do if I'm stuck in XF 4.4?

Comment: @chung What's your problem in XF4.4?

Comment: I have a loading icon that won't disappear from the middle of my screen. It seems like everything has loaded already, I can input text into text boxes, scroll around, etc. but the icon won't disappear

Comment: @chung You should open a new thread and add your code there, then we can help you better. Also, this may caused by the UIWebView as I answered in your another question. You can mark/upvote this answer if it helps you.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT, I already have another mtouch argument in my ios Projects, How can I add it in addition to the existing one Whether just space is enough or I have to separate them using coma. And what if there is any 3rd party packages which are using Xamarin.Forms<4.5.