# Is my CustomWebViewRenderer enough for Xamarin Forms or do I need to use the official one on GitHub?

Tags: xamarin.forms

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/WkWebViewRenderer.cs This link shows a WebView Renderer and it has 400 lines!

I was just using the default WKWebView when I came across a loading icon bug and I found a suggestion online to make a WebView Renderer, which looks like this:

```
using MyApp.Mobile.Common.iOS.Renderers;
using Foundation;
using WebKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(BetterWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Mobile.Common.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class BetterWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<WebView, WKWebView>
    {
        WKWebView _wkWebView;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                _wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                SetNativeControl(_wkWebView);
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(((UrlWebViewSource)Element.Source).Url)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After this fix, it looks like nothing has changed from before, except the loading icon bug (where the loading icon wouldn't disapppear from the middle of the page) is now gone and everything seems normal (which is great), but comparing it to the one on GitHub, it looks like I did something wrong?

When I create a custom renderer, do all of the features disappear and I have to code for them again? For example, in the link I shared there are methods like `LoadHtml`, `Dispose` and `OnReloadRequested`. Do I need to include them in my renderer? When everything appears to be working okay without all of this?

I'm very confused... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All of the features do not disappear thanks to inheritance and overriding methods.

When you did this line:

`BetterWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<WebView, WKWebView>`

you were saying you wanted your **BetterWebViewRenderer** to inherit from the existing **ViewRenderer** that Xamarin setup.

See [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance) for more details on how inheritance works.

You can also see their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) for override methods.

Comment: Ok, and can you explain what ViewRenderer<WebView, WKWebView> means? I'm not sure what that syntax would be. Why wouldn't I just inherit directly from WKWebView by doing BetterWebViewRenderer : WKWebView?

Answer (score 0):

When you use default WebView in Xamarin.forms, as I mentioned in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60143577/10539446), before Xamarin.forms 4.5, Xamarin use [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview?language=objc)(Which is deprecated in iOS12) and this may cause the icon issue.

In your question, you write a custom renderer of WebView which use [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview?language=objc), then the url will load by `WKWebView` in iOS not `UIWebView`. Which may fix the issue.

Both `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` are native controls in iOS.

You can use `WkWebViewRenderer` directly as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview#create-the-custom-renderer-on-ios) in the document:

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
```

You do not need to include all the methods in the `WkWebViewRenderer` because `HybridWebViewRenderer` inherits from `WkWebViewRenderer`, methods in the `WkWebViewRenderer` will also be executed you use `HybridWebViewRenderer`.

You can `override` those methods to perform your own action if you want.